# No sound after changing project name iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

im having trouble with my iOS application. After changing product name by double-clicking project icon on XCode (i don't know if this is a proper way - I found this solution on stackoverflow), my application doesn't play sound.

I have my mp3 files in resources. Code for playing sound:

```
 NSString* pathToResource = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[SIWordsDatabase sharedDatabase].currentWord ofType:@"mp3"];
NSLog(@"%@", pathToResource);
NSLog(@"exist? : %i", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToResource]);
if(pathToResource && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToResource]){
    NSURL* soundURL = [NSURL URLWithString:pathToResource];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, &mySound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
    NSLog(@"playing 2");
    return;
}
```

Log:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/E8159EA0-2980-4DEE-95BB-E0D1D37AAB19/MyAppName.app/pig.mp3
exist? : 1
playing 2
```

Before changing name it was working...

Any ideas?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

To rename your project do like Apple indicates in the documentation.

From Apple documentation :

"To rename your application, modify the Project Name field if you are using Xcode 4 or later or use the Rename feature if you are using Xcode 3.2.x."

Xcode 4.0 or later

Follow these steps to rename your application in Xcode 4.0 or later:

1. In Xcode, select your target under "Targets" in the project editor, then choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector.
2. Xcode opens the file inspector pane. Enter your application's new name in the Project Name field,
   then hit the return key on your keyboard.
3. Xcode displays a project-rename dialog that contains all the items that can be renamed in your project. Leave your application selected in the dialog and deselect all other items

[Application rename Xcode - Technical Q&A QA1625](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html)

For the sound that's not playing, the documentation says that sound file that you can play with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` should be Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav. In your example you have .mp3 sound file.

Comment: Yes, i have .mp3 sound file but before renaming project it was working :) Alsa i have another project that uses the same function and it works.

Comment: Strange :),Undo your work about renaming Xcode and do it like the documentation says.

Comment: I made this, but the problem was with new name. It must not contain spaces. Now it's working. Big thanks for reply! :)